# npm hfc@0.6.2 not properly installing

Tags: npm, npm-install, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

how to solve this problem.

I run this commands make node-sdk on hyperledger/fabric folder (with sudo or without), still i am getting the same errors.

[npm WARM hfc@0.6.2 license should be a valid SPDX license expression log file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPwf8.png)

Answer (score 0):

this is harmless, the hfc module should still work despite the warning. By the way, if you are still developing with Hyperledger Fabric, there's a v1.0 release now. Checkout the details at hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/